# Search database with 6 user inputs

Tags: php, sql, advanced-search

I have a database with vehicle information in it (make, model, year, branch, etc)

I need to create a search form to search this database. The search form consists of 4 selection boxes and two text boxes.

Please find the code below trying to query the database:

```
<?php

      $dbName = "F:/Domains/autodeal/autodeal.co.za/wwwroot/newsite/db/savvyautoweb.mdb";

      // Throws an error if the database cannot be found
      if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
        die("Could not find database file.");
      }

      // Connects to the database
      // Assumes there is no username or password
      $conn = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", '', '');

      if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        $searchMake = addslashes($_POST['makeSelection']);
        $searchModel = addslashes($_POST['modelSelection']);
        $searchBranch = addslashes($_POST['branchSelection']);
        $searchYear = addslashes($_POST['yearSelection']);
        $minPrice = addslashes($_POST['minPriceSelection']);
        $maxPrice = addslashes($_POST['maxPriceSelection']);

        $sql = "SELECT Id, Make, Model, Year, Price, SpecialPrice, Branch, StockNO FROM Vehicle WHERE Price >= '$minPrice' AND Price <= '$maxPrice' AND Make LIKE '$searchMake' AND Model LIKE '$searchModel' AND Branch LIKE '$searchBranch' AND Year LIKE '$searchYear'";
        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);

      } else {
        $sql = "SELECT Id, Make, Model, Year, Price, SpecialPrice, Branch, StockNO FROM Vehicle ORDER BY Make";
        $rs = odbc_exec($conn, $sql);
      }          

          echo "\t" . "<tr>\n";

              echo "\t" . "<th>Make</th><th>Model</th><th>Year</th><th>Price</th><th>Special Price</th><th>Location</th><th>Stock Number</th>" . "\n";

                  while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) { 
                      $id = odbc_result($rs, Id);
                      $make = odbc_result($rs, Make);
                      $model = odbc_result($rs, Model);
                      $year = odbc_result($rs, Year);
                      $price = odbc_result($rs, Price);
                      $specialPrice = odbc_result($rs, SpecialPrice);
                      $branch = odbc_result($rs, Branch);
                      $stockNo = odbc_result($rs, StockNO);

                          echo "\t" . "<tr>\n";
                              echo "\t\t" . "<td>" . $make . "</td><td><a href=/newsite/selected-vehicles?Id=$id>" . $model . "</a></td><td>" . $year . "</td><td>" . $price . "</td><td>" . $specialPrice . "</td><td>" . $branch . "</td><td>" . $stockNo . "</td>\n";

                          echo "\t" . "</tr>\n";
                  }

      odbc_free_result($rs);
      odbc_close($conn);

      // This message is displayed if the query has an error in it
      if (!$rs) {
          exit("There is an error in the SQL!");
      }

  ?>
```

When I run this script, "there is an error in the SQL" message appears.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thannk you

Comment: "there is an error in the SQL" does not give us enough details to debug this problem.

Comment: Debug using `or die(odbc_errormsg());` after your each `odbc_exec` statement.

Comment: This is the error I get: `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

Comment: non-escaped inputs, likes without wild cards there's a list of issues as long as my arm here to fix which if you do will probably fix all your other issues at the same time

Comment: I strongly urge you to read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!! With this code you are opening up the whole database to malicious users - and you posted the URL as well...

Comment: @SebastianH I sanitized the inputs to prevent injection. Now would it be possible to assist in my actual question?

Comment: `Data type mismatch` sounds like a precise error message. What is the data type of the columns `Price` and `Year` in your database? Your program tries to compare them to string values.

Comment: They are integers. I never looked at it in that way. Does that mean that the text boxes for the year and the price should be of number type?

Answer (score 0):

The sql query which you are making depending upon the user inputs should be modified as   there is huge chances it will fail as user may or may not enter all the text boxes. Basically, you you create dynamic query with `if else` conditions

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, Make, Model, Year, Price, SpecialPrice, Branch, StockNO FROM Vehicle WHERE 1 = 1; 

if ($minPrice > -1 )
{
  $sql  .=  $sql  " and  Price >= $minPrice ";
}
```

Similarly for others and in comparison operators `>` `<` you shouldn't add single quotes with price.

Try to print your query and check how is it formed-

Comment: If I use your code above, what happens to the rest of the inputted data, the make, the model, the branch and the year? And I definitely agree that most of the time, not all the inputs will be completed. If not all the inputs are completed and only, say two were, results pertaining to only those two need to be echod.